# Can I use a template to set Grammar/Proofing Settings?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, templates, grammar, proofing

I am trying to create/update an existing template for my job, and include many checklist items.  My team is only 3 other writers + me, but there may be more.

Windows 10 machines, Word 2016.

Some of our Checklist items include punctuation inside the question mark and two spaces after periods. (It's a rule in our style guide).  I also have a personal preference for the serial comma.
Fortunately, `File --> Options --> Proofing --> Style and Grammar area --> Settings` allows me to turn these on as things to flag.

[Grammar Check Settings box image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRe9I.png)

But can I turn it on for anyone else?

I do see a macro here ( https://wordribbon.tips.net/T010775_An_Automatic_Two_Spaces_after_a_Period.html --near the bottom of the article) 
that allows a search-replace for always getting 2 spaces after a period, but can I macro-ize the rest?  I'd prefer if I can just embed the grammar-check preferences into the template.

*(I'll be asking a few other template-possibility questions -- it's my understanding that it's better to have distinct questions, so someone can answer each element individually, but if I should merge these, let me know. Thanks!)*

Comment: You can do this with group policy. Are your computers members of an active directory domain?

Comment: You may define Auto-Correct entries in *File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options* and transfer them to other computers as an `.acl` files or in `normal.dotm`. That's about the maximum you can do without a VBA macro.

Comment: I don't think I have Active Directory editing powers -- big organization, and I'm  a tiny finish in a tiny team that's an orphan between two departments.

Comment: I do have a book on learning VBA arriving soon, so I will  see if I can expand the given macro.